# Novell Breaks Windows7

Tags: windows-7

I am a student worker here at my University. We use Novell for logging in and Zenworks for multiple things. I work in our imaging department, we basically do hardware level troubleshooting and put our University image via PXE boot on machines. I was told to just leave this problem alone and rebuild the machine. The thing is, we have had 3 different machines do this and nobody has any clue.

Here is the problem:

Desktop tech's get a ticket about user having problems logging to the machine. As a student worker, I go with to expand my knowledge. So we get there and we are looking at Novell Login and I type my credentials to see if I can login. We can't. Novell says 'Waiting for network to initialize'. Thought fair enough, tried to do a windows only login and it works. No Novell services were able to be used (Shared Drivers). Also, we install Microsoft Office on every machine as our standard build process, path to the Office suite was broken. I figured that it had lost its license to, but no it didn't. Safe to say, Windows was broken.

So from here we tried some basic troubleshooting. Firstly, restart the computer. Didnt work.

Tried to start the Novell Services, didnt work. Switched ports on the switch, didnt work.

Tried to reinstall Novell, didnt work. Looked for virus on the users profile, didnt find anything.

Looked for viruses in the Shared Drive, nothing. Look for viruses on USB drives, nothing was found.

So we thought maybe it is a network problem,we had her login into another machine on a different subnet, she signed in just fine.

So we figured, one time thing, not a big deal. We are in the process of rebuilding her machine (Which implies a data backup, deleting windows, reinstalling windows, and transfer data back on, about a 2 day process). In the middle of me rebuilding her machine, the rental we gave her, same thing happens. This time it is worse. All the same symptoms but we cant log into Windows at all.

At this point I was told not to worry about it and to just keep on with my job (They basically said you dont get paid enough to worry about this). So I did, we are busy and they were right, this doesn't pertain me.

Well a few days ago, I get another machine, same exact thing happens. Different user, different subnet. I am at lost with what is happening. Windows is completely broken, cant login.

Any ideas on what is happening here? Thank you.

Comment: As a student you should be aware of the existence of paragraphs and the <Enter> key. Please [edit] your question to use them. At the moment it is an **unreadable wall of text**. You can refer to [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) if you get stuck ;)

Answer (score 0):

With a Novell/Windows login question, you need to be sure what network protocols the novell server is using to connect to the users. The original Novell network protocol is IPX/SPX. Commonly, Windows machines connecting to Novell servers would have their credentials checked locally by the actual Windows machine, and also separately, by the Novell server. When working properly this would be transparent to the user.
I am afraid you haven't provided enough information for me to ascertain
what protocols are in use.

A useful test would be to configure a windows machine without any (Windows) network drivers, and then to install a Novell client only, and see if that connects to the server.

The different protocols are confusing, but it is key that IPX/SPX is the native Novell protocol. Later versions of Novell developed TCP/IP clients that were able to provide the IPX/SPX to the Novell server, and also provide the Windows protocols  so that Microsoft servers could be seen. Microsoft also developed an IPX/SPX protocol that allowed their machines to connect to Novell, so, you could check the network protocols on the client machines and make sure that IPX/SPX is there. If that is all that is wrong it's a very quick fix.